# Javascript window.opener not working in asp.net mvc-5

Tags: javascript, window.open, window.opener

I am creating a web app in `asp.net mvc` in which I am redirecting from one view to another using window.open

> here is my code in javascript

```
window.open('@Url.Action("Details", "Details"), "_self");
```

I have some variable in JS which I declared in script Tag like the following

```
var1 = "0";
var2 = "2";
var3 = "0";
var4 = "0";
```

but after redirecting I am not able to get the values of these variable

when I type `console.log(window.parent.var2);`

I am expecting to get `2` but actually I am getting `undefined`

what I need to do, to use `Javascript's` window.opener in `asp.net mvc`

Comment: removed asp.net tag as it is not related to MVC .net and is just a javascript question, the url helper is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change this

```
window.open('@Url.Action("Details", "Details"), "_self");
```

to

```
window.open('@Url.Action("Details", "Details"), "_blank");
```

it would work but you would have two windows open.
window.opener and window.parent only works if both the opener and opened window/page are both open. Neither work on a _self link.

Comment: ok thanks, is there anything which can work on _self?, except (session,localstorage,cookie)

Comment: nope, because you are actually loading a new page in the same window/tab there is no opener/parent. It simply is not a concept unless one window opens another window. Beyond what you listed you should probably add the value you are interested in to the query string which in mvc would be something like @Url.Action("Details","Details",new {val2 = 2},null)